Passing change event value through props from child component to parent in react typescript
I'm trying to pass data from child component to parent one through change event.
But I can't understand,  basically both functions have the same structure.
The main components is getting bigger so I'm trying to break it down into some smaller components.
Parent component:
  const handleChange =
    (name: string) => (event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement  > ) => {
      const target = event?.target as HTMLInputElement 
      let file: File;
      let value;
      if (target.files as FileList) {
        file = (target.files as FileList)[0];
        value = name === "photo" ? file : event?.currentTarget.value;
        if (name === "photo") {
          formData.append("photo", file);
          setImage(URL.createObjectURL(file));
        }
      } else {
        value = event?.currentTarget.value;
        formData.set(name, value);
        setValues({ ...values, [name as string]: value });
      }
    };
  return (
 <RenderCategories handleChange={handleChange('category')} />
)

Child components:
interface FuncProps{
    handleChange:(name:string)=>(event:FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>)=>void
}
const RenderCategories = (props:FuncProps) => {
    const [categories,setCategories]=useState([])

    const loadCategories= ()=>{
        getCategories().then((data)=>{
            if(data.error){
                console.log(data.error)
            }else{
                setCategories(data)
            }
        })
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        loadCategories()
    },[])
    return (
        <div className="col-12 col-md-6 ">
           
             <label htmlFor="categorySelect" className="form-label required " >
                  Category
                </label>
                <select
                  className="form-control form-select "
                  onChange={props.handleChange("category")}
                
                >
                 <option>Select one</option>
                  {categories &&
                    categories?.map((c: any, i: any) => {
                    return  <option key={i} value={c._id}>
                        {c.name}
                      </option>
})}
                </select>
             
            </div> 
      );

I tried various ways but couldn't get rid of this error:

Type '(event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(name: string) => (event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>) => void'.
Types of parameters 'event' and 'name' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>'


In your Parent Component, your handleChange function is indeed of type (name: string) => (event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>) => void, i.e. it builds another function of type (event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>) => void, which is indeed suitable as an Event Listener.
But in the JSX template of your Parent Component, you already execute once your handleChange function (as handleChange('category')). Therefore what you provide to your prop is no longer your handleChange function builder, but its result, i.e. directly an Event Listener. Hence the error message.
In your case, you could simply make sure to pass down your handleChange function builder to your Child Component:
<RenderCategories
  handleChange={handleChange} // Pass directly `handleChange`, do not execute it as `handleChange('category')`
/>

Another possible solution, depending on how exactly you would like to decouple your Components, would consist in changing the Child prop to actually take an Event Listener directly, which is more common:
// Parent Component as initially

// Child Component:
interface FuncProps {
  // Take directly an Event Listener
  handleChange: (event:FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>) => void
}

const RenderCategories = (props: FuncProps) => {
  // etc.
  return (
    // etc.
    <select
      className="form-control form-select"
      onChange={props.handleChange} // Pass directly the Event Listener
    >
    // etc.
  );
}


due to the structure that i use, i need the name of the elements to pass it to the form data; therefore, your first solution works fine with me thanks a lot
